# Node.js C++ extension deployment

Tags: node.js, deployment, shared

I followed [Writing Node.js Native Extension](https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/aug/23/writing-nodejs-native-extensions/) and created `helloworld.node` file successfully. And I am able to call the `helloworld.node` successfully.

Moreover, I have a `test.js` for calling `helloworld.node`. The content of `test.js` is

```
var mhw = require('./helloworld/build/Release/helloworld');
var hw = new mhw.HelloWorld();
console.log(hw.hello());
```

But I got `Unable to load shared library` error after I moved `helloworld.node` and `test.js` to another computer.

```
hkalex(at)shellmix ~/nodetest> node test.js

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Unable to load shared library /homex/hkalex/nodetest/helloworld/build/Release/helloworld.node
    at Object..node (module.js:463:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/homex/hkalex/nodetest/test.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
hkalex(at)shellmix ~/nodetest>
```

I am using `root` in the developing computer. And I am using `shellmix` for testing.

Have any idea? Thanks!

**Update**

If I put the source file in `shellmix` and compile from source, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the on the other machine you don't have the same CPU architecture or operating system, and you have machine specific code. Usually for node native modules, they distribute the source, and compile automatically on npm install on the target machine, to make sure it works on their machine. If using gcc, you can specify the cpu architecture(adding -m32 or -m64).

If you want to compile for another OS, the easiest way is to just compile on the OS which you can also have it on a virtual machine using [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/overview.html).

You can also have compile for other OS than the one you are using a cross compiler, but that is not recommended since, it would take some time to build and learn to use. Instructions are [here](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) and [here](http://www.nongnu.org/thug/cross.html) .